# Change sub folder from user on windows 10

Tags: windows-10

Here is C:\Users\manth> folder on my windows 10 now i want it change it to C:\Users\manthan>
how can it be changed?
I tried to change the folder by renaming it but not worked.

Answer (score 1):

The process looks as follows.

Open the command prompt with Administrator privileges, type **wmic useraccount list full** then hit Enter.
Scroll down until you find SID and copy its values for the account you want to change.

Clear the screen by typing **cls**.

Type **cd c:\users** then hit Enter.
Type **rename OldAccountName NewAccountName**

Open registry editor as an administrator.
Start, type **regedit**

Right-click and select Run as administrator.

Navigate to

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList
```

Look for a similar SID value that you copied earlier.
Once you find it, double-click the value **ProfileImagePath**.
You will see the old name, change it to the new name you want to use and it is done.

Answer (score 0):

you have to create a user as "manthan" either change the username. because it is the user dir.